# Extract OLE Object (word document) from Access DB

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a Microsoft Access 2000 database. I am accessing it through Office 2007. I have Word and text(.txt) files as OLE objects in the database, the contents of which need to be shown in a report. I am using a Bound Object Frame, the source of which is set to the table's column containing these documents.

The problem is no text shows up in the Bound Object Frame in either Report or Design View, even if there are only a few characters in the file. Any suggestions to what I'm missing out?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982688/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982688/) has a brief explanation of why storing a JPEG is a bad idea using OLE in MS Access DB.  It's likely that similar bitmap records are being created for your documents.  IF that is the case, then simply selecting the OLE Record form the table is not enough as the rest of the actual content of the documents are stored as a different record in a bitmap table.  Have you considered storing only a link to the file in a table, then transfer the text from the document into the form?

Comment: @TexasTubbs: Thank you for the comment. I did consider about storing the link to the file in a table, but the database usually transferred to different machines using any storage medium.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see how the OLE Objects are being inserted.  Is the "Linked" checkbox checked or not?  Then check the "OLE Type Allowed" property on the data tab of the Bound Object Frame's properties.  Hopefully it matches with what the "Linked" checkbox says?

Otherwise, maybe try just dragging the OLE field directly onto the report and see if the default settings that Access uses make it work?  (Not sure if that's what you did or if you manually put a Bound Object Frame and set its record source)

Just a couple initial troubleshooting suggestions...