# Why size of .mdb growing three times with small image?

Tags: image, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I made few forms in Access 2010 and I add logo of company to the header form. This picture is .jpg and size of it is 70KB. I don't know why size of .mdb immediately increased from 4MB to 12MB? (few forms and the same logo) Maybe there is some options of image compression ?

Comment: Someone with knowledge of Access 2010 in particular should answer this, but in older versions of Access images were not stored in their compressed format and so adding a small JPG could drastically increase DB size. Have you tried compacting the DB to see if that made a difference?

Comment: Compacting doesn't change much. In my case there was 12,4 MB and now it is 11,9 MB.

Comment: @pstrjds I am not exactly sure how this works, but mdb is the older format and, I suspect, subject to the bloat that was a problem for the older versions. I wonder would it be worth trying the accdb format?

Comment: @Remou That sounds reasonable. I suppose it depends if it needs to be an `mdb` file or if a newer format would be acceptable. I don't normally work with Access anymore and I don't know what the tradeoffs between MDB and ACCDB are, but it does appear (from quick search and scan of returned documents) that you should get better binary data storage so I would suspect that it will handle the jpg natively as opposed to storing it as a bmp.

Comment: Indeed. It saves 2MB. So I've got 10MB. I was thinking about 2-3 MB for my application. It is strange how 70KB image can be stored by Access in duplicated size?

Comment: How will the database be distributed? You can take an image on a form and change it to Linked instead of Embedded as long as the end users have access to the jpg file.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/store-images-in-a-database-HP005280225.aspx

> ..."However, embedding images can rapidly inflate the size of your
>   database and cause it to run slowly. This is especially true if you
>   store GIF and JPEG files, because OLE creates additional bitmap files
>   that contain display information for each of your image files, and
>   those additional files can be larger than your original images. In
>   addition, this method only supports the Windows Bitmap (.bmp) and
>   Device Independent Bitmap (.dib) graphic file formats. If you want to
>   display other common types of image files, such as GIF and JPEG
>   images, you have to install additional software."...

To explain how these bitmap files are stored, the link below offers more explanation than the microsoft site:

Taken from http://www.ammara.com/support/kb/showkbe5cc.html

> ..."OLE Linking & Embedding is a technique used by Microsoft Access to
>   store 'Objects' in database tables.The technique relies on the
>   associated external application to store, present and edit the data.
>   In some cases an additional uncompressed 'preview' image is also saved
>   in the table (even when linking). This preview image is used for
>   faster display of the data, or when the server application isn't
>   available. This can cause a massive overhead. If you're storing jpeg
>   images the uncompressed preview can be ten or twenty times the actual
>   image size, causing the size of the database to rocket."...

So, when you drop an image onto a form in MS Access, uncompressed image data is saved to the system tables.  This is actual uncompressed table data, so a compact and repair may offer little help.

The common workaround seems to be store the path to the image in a database table, and use that path to invoke the image on the form.

Comment: thanks for the formatting edits, @EBarr!  It looks way better now!

Comment: Glad to be of service ...just browsing in idle time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know WHY (and I don't care) but I already noticed that behaviour as well. My workaround for company logos or equivalent is to insert it in ONE form, which I then insert  as a subform wherever I need it. It has the added benefit that if the logo changes one day, there is only one place to update.