# MS Access form size increases when background image added

Tags: ms-access, jpeg, ms-access-forms

I have a JPEG file which I would like to use as a background picture of all of the forms in my MS Access Database. The picture size is about 80 kilobytes. However, for every form I add it to, the database size increases by approximately 12 megabytes and does not decrease after Compact and Repair. Why is this happening and what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why size of .mdb growing three times with small image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982688/why-size-of-mdb-growing-three-times-with-small-image)

Comment: Thanks Rene, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution, but not sure if the problem is going to return at some point.

1. Create an empty Access database and import all objects from the original database.
2. Remove all background images from all forms in the new database.
3. Compact and Repair new database. Not sure if this step is required, but I did it.
4. Add all background images again.

Simply moving all objects to a new file didn't work, neither did deleting and re-uploading the background images in the old file, so seems like both actions are required.

If anyone explains why this issue is happening and offers a better solution, I'm happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: In access there is a setting to use the "older" legacy image format. It bloats like crazy. The newer image  format does not bloat. When you created the new database, likely the setting defaulted to the new image format. The older database likely had it roots and originated from a older pre-2007 format, so it defaulted to the  old format. You can  change this setting by file->options->current Database. In that property sheet you find a setting under Picture Property Storage format. You want to select "Preserve source image format". as opposed to convert all pictures to bitmaps (2003 format).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, thanks for the suggestion, but seems like it's not the case. the database file was created a few months ago, and the Picture Property Storage Format is already set to Preserve source image format.